# h4 googleusercontent 404 error on some google profile image photos

Tags: android, http-status-code-404

I am using Google Sign-in API for my app, so as a part of it I am getting the URL of users google profile photos. 
For some users an issue occurs that the URL for their photo gets 404 response, so I use a default placeholder image for them.
here is the link to one of the images I get that does not work -

`https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-hq1diiDJ-JQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACLGyWBDwVN6t-GDXdfMtKakTWGfQ_MsIA/s96-c/photo.jpg`

I can't figure out what is wrong with the lh4 google URL's for some users and I was lucky enough to get a live example of one of the users that has this issue so I can eventually reproduce it.

Anyone has any ideas about this issue? it is something to do with my code or something to do internally with googles API ?